# Handling enter key event in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a component in my application.It have a form  with text fields.It will have a submit button.When submit is pressed it will send a post request to the server.I also handled a keyboard event in components js file.When enter is pressed it will send a post request to the server.When the enter key is pressed two times continuously it is making two post request to the server with first request success and second request failed.
I want to make my app in such away even if the user presses the enter key two times continuously it should send only one post request to the server.Can any one help me solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

*components js file:*

```
export default Component.extend({
  keyDown:function(event){
            let self = this;
            if(event.keyCode === 13){
              self.send('submitform'); 
              return false;
  }
  actions: {
             submitform(){
             //logic to handle the post request to the server    
  }   
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to checkout [ember-concurrency](http://ember-concurrency.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try usig [Ember.run.debounce](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_debounce),

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    keyDown: function(event) {
        let self = this;
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            // self.send('submitform');
            Ember.run.debounce(self,self.get('submitform'),400);
            return false;
        }
    },
    submitform(){
        //handle submit form logic
    }
});
```

You can play with [twiddle here](https://ember-twiddle.com/2710b8ff24248dca64cc32b3c9e6cef7?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)

Comment: Is there anyway to disable keyboard event in ember?so that i can enable key board event initially.Once enter is pressed is pressed i can disable the keyboard event.So that no further request to the server is made.

Comment: Did you try my answer ?

Comment: Ya I tried it but still when I press Enter twice continuously It is triggering the keyDown event twice and submitForm method twice and making two request to the server with first being success next being failed.It will be better to do like when enter is pressed for the first time I can disable keyboard event Enter similar to disabling buttons.So that even the user presses Enter continuously the first enter alone will make a request to the server.Is there anyway to do like that?

Comment: @bharathwajravi disabling key board event is not the right approach. I updated my answer with twiddle you can check it out.

Comment: is there any way to count the number of times an Enter key is pressed?

Comment: Debouncing waits for an arbitrary amount of seconds before allowing the `submitForm()` again. What if the debounce is 500ms and the requests takes 2000ms to resolve, that means users can submit  again before the request is resolved. I much recommend using an event-driven approach using promises instead.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to disable `submitForm()` until your POST request is complete. You can do this by setting a property `submitting` on the component and turning it on before the POST and off once the promise is resolved. Perhaps try something like:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  submitting: false,
  keyDown: function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      this.submitform();
    }
  },
  submitform() {
    // Run only if not currently submitting
    if (!this.get('submitting')) {
      // What to do when submit succeeds
      const success = () => {
        this.set('submitting', false);
      }
      // What to do when submit fails
      const fail = () => {
        this.set('submitting', false);
      }
      // Do the POST request
      this.set('submitting', true);
      this.get('someModel').save().then(success).catch(fail);
    };
  }
});
```

And, unrelated, this allows you to do fun things with your template such as disabling and styling the submit button for as long as the POST promise is not resolved yet:

```
<button {{action 'submitForm'}} disabled={{submitting}} class="{{if submitting 'loading'}}">
  {{#if submitting}}
    Submitting ...
  {{else}}
    Submit
  {{/if}}
</button>
```

Oh and lastly, no need to use `let self = this;` anymore. Use ES6 arrow functions `() => { ... }` instead so you can keep using `this` inside.